# How to simulate a taskrouter system event

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

To be more precise, is there any way to simulate TaskRoute's "task.system-deleted" event?

Where can I configure the event TTL?

I didn't find anything in the documentation (https://www.twilio.com/docs/taskrouter/api/event/reference)

Comment: How can i get task.system_delete event callback?
When i try to get through ngrok and added endpoint to settings. I was unable to get system delete event is triggered. but its actually canceled and deleted from the twilio task.

Can you help me in this?

Answer (score 0):

The "[Delete a Task](https://www.twilio.com/docs/taskrouter/api/task?code-sample=code-delete-a-task&code-language=C%23&code-sdk-version=6.x)" example shows how to delete a task:

```
// Install the C# / .NET helper library from twilio.com/docs/csharp/install

using System;
using Twilio;
using Twilio.Rest.Taskrouter.V1.Workspace;


class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Find your Account SID and Auth Token at twilio.com/console
        // and set the environment variables. See http://twil.io/secure
        string accountSid = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID");
        string authToken = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN");

        TwilioClient.Init(accountSid, authToken);

        TaskResource.Delete(
            pathWorkspaceSid: "WSXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
            pathSid: "WTXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
        );
    }
}
```